# Electron with React and Firebase login pop-up issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, variables, electron, popup

So, I have a ReactApp, it uses firebase to login, and, after the login, you can use the app.
But, when trying to log in, the pop-up window open and, after some seconds, it closes without letting me login.
I think the problem is within electron somewhere, just can't see where, here is the error message it gives me when trying to open the pop-up:

> Error occurred in handler for 'ELECTRON_GUEST_WINDOW_MANAGER_WINDOW_METHOD': Error invalid guestId:2

I'll leave part of the code here so you can see how it is written.
Here's the electron code:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  win.loadURL(
      isDev ? "http://localhost:3000"
        : 
      `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
    )
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Here's the firebase code:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const database = firebase.database()
const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

export { firebase, googleAuthProvider, database as default }
```

And here is the redux action to make the auth:

```
export const startLogin = () => {
    return () => {
        return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add nativeWindowOpen inside webPreferences.
In the end that part should look like

```
 const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 680,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      nativeWindowOpen: true,
    },
  });
```

After adding this you should see popup.

[image]

More about this you can read here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/22898